# Does there exist two infinite subsets of naturals $A, B$ such that each $n \in A + B$ uniquely determines $a \in A, b \in B$ such that $a + b = n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computer-science, products, binary, natural-numbers

Does there exist two infinite sets of naturals $A, B$ such that each $n \in A + B = \{ a + b : a\in A, b\in B\}$ has a unique solution $a + b = n$ in which $a \in A, b \in B$?

For example:

$$
A = \{0,3,6\} \\
B = \{0,2,7\} \\ \implies \\
0 = 0 + 0 \text{ is unique } \\
0 = 0 + 2 \text{ is unique } \\
\vdots \\
6 + 7 = 13 \text{ is unique }
$$

But I need the sets $A, B$ to be infinite.

I need it so that when multiplying two numbers in binary:

$$
(\sum_{i \in A}^{\infty} a_i 2^i)(\sum_{j \in B}^{\infty} b_j 2^j)
$$

Each coefficient is of the form $a_i b_j$ for some $i, j$ and so that the position $i$ that $a_i$ came from and the position $j$ that $b_j$ came from is uniquely determined by the value $i + j$.

---

I only need to always be able to determine two finite sets $A, B$ of roughly the same size such that $|A||B| = |A + B| = N^2$ for any $N \in \Bbb{N}$, which is why infinity came to mind, but an algorithm that returns the two finite sets given $N$ is sufficient for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $A,B$ as follows . . .

- Let $A$ be the set of positive integers of the form $2^s$ where $s$ is even.

  Let $B$ be the set of positive integers of the form $2^t$ where $t$ is odd.

If for $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, we have 
$$n=a+b=2^s+2^t$$
where $s$ is even and $t$ is odd, then $s,t$ are uniquely determined by $n$, hence so are $a,b$.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Let $A$ be the powers of 10, and $B$ be $\{2, 22, 222, 2222, \dotsc\}$.

Numbers in $A+B$ are either of a form like 1000022222, or like 2223222, and in either case you can determine what $a$ and $b$ are.

If you want more numbers in the sets, we can generalize quasi's answer:
Let $A$ be the sums of distinct odd powers of two, and $B$ be the sums of distinct even powers of two. Then each set has 32 elements below 1000, which is better than the 3 each in my answer, or the 5 each in quasi's answer. $A$ starts with $\{0, 2, 8, 10, 32, 34, \dotsc\}$ and $B$ starts with $\{0, 1, 4, 5, 16, 17, 20, \dotsc\}$.

Then the number of elements in $A$ or $B$ less than any given $N$
is about $2^{\log_2(N)/2}$: for half the available bit positions (either the even or odd ones), you make a choice between putting a 0 or 1 there.
This is about $\sqrt{N}$.
By the pigeonhole principle, the best you can do is less than $\sqrt{2N}$, so this is close to optimal.

Comment: Now a bonus question: Is exponentially sparse sets the best you can do?

Comment: Yeah, I would like to see non-infinitely sparse because these indices correspond to vertices of a graph, and if I'm working with a large graph, then any algorithm that uses plain integer indices will become exponential!

Comment: @StudySmarterNotHarder: Well, quasi's answer is still exponentially sparse. You can do somewhat better by letting A be the nonzero sums of distinct odd powers of two, and B be the nonzero sums of distinct even powers of two. Then each set has 31 elements below 1000, which is better than the 3 each in my answer, or the 5 each in quasi's answer.

Comment: @IgorRivin: Well, if the sets A and B contained at least 1/a of the natural numbers below each N, then by choosing N > 2a^2, the number of sums in A + B with summands less than N is greater than N^2/a^2 > 2N, so by the pigeonhole principle some sums must collide. In fact we see the number of elements less than N must be less than $\sqrt{2N}$. The sums of odd / even powers of 2 I mentioned in my comment come close to this bound.